# Python import issue for different subpackages

Tags: python, python-import, python-module, pythonpath

I am trying to implement following hierarchy.
My final goal is myscpt.sh should run from any folder

But I am getting import errors.

What is the best approach to implement such type of hierarchical architecture?

```
FooSoft
|
|-- foo/
    |
    |-- test.py   
    |
    |-- common/     
    |
    |-- utils/
    |
    |-- api/
    |
    |-- scripts/
          |-- myscript.py
|
|-- bin/myscpt.sh
|
|-- etc/foo.conf
```

bin/myscpt.sh

```
/usr/bin/python /path/FooSoft/foo/script/myscript.py /path/FooSoft/etc/foo.conf
```

foo/script/myscript.py

```
from ..common import *
from ..utils import *
from ..test import *
.
.
<Doing some stuff>
```

I am using `.. import` in most of modules to avoid absolute path.

Answer (score 1):

Typically I resolve import errors by always using the package root as a reference.

First, I would include a setup.py file in the project root, and add in a [minimal setuptools wrapper](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#basic-use).

```
python setup.py develop
```

Then you don't have to worry about where you run the script from.  Your imports become as follows:

```
from foo.common import *
from foo.utils import *
from foo.test import *
```

Answer (score 0):

Explicit relative imports with leading dots like `from ..common import anything` can be used only from a code that has been imported as a submodule of the package e.g. `foo.scripts`, but not from the the code imported as `__main__` script, even if the script path contains `.../foo/scripts/...`. The main script must use absolute imports or it can be used as module by something like `python -c "from foo.scripts import myscript; myscript.run()"`.  (install the foo or use PYTHONPATH=/path/FooSoft). See [Intra-package References](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references) in the docs or a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72852/how-to-do-relative-imports-in-python?rq=1).